# how to run mongodb replica set in docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have tried to run mongodb replicaSet in local with mongoldb-community in my Mac I follow [mongodb doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) I can run it by this command

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,127.0.0.1
```

but it doesn't run on background, so every time I want to start replica set mongodb I should run that command, before I run it `I should stop mongo` first, then on the next tab console I should run `mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"` to create to replicaSet again

here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

how to convert that into docker-compose ? is it possible ?

can I do `docker exec CONTAINER_ID [commands]` ? to run command mongo like above , but must stop the mongodb run in that docker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a mongodb replica-set with this docker-compose services:

```
mongodb-primary:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb-persistence/bitnami:/bitnami
    networks:
      - parse_network
    environment:
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=123456789
      - MONGODB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin-123
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password-123
      - MONGODB_USERNAME=admin-123
      - MONGODB_PASSWORD=password-123
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=my_database
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  mongodb-secondary:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=123456789
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER=27017
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_USERNAME=admin-123
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password-123
    networks:
      - parse_network
    ports:
      - 27027:27017

  mongodb-arbiter:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-arbiter
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=arbiter
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_PORT_NUMBER=27017
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password-123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=123456789
    networks:
      - parse_network
    ports:
      - 27037:27017

networks:
  parse_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
volumes:
  mongodb_master_data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: what is the URI for connect into my app ? should I use that URI into my mongo compass ? with that credential ?

Comment: `mongodb://admin-123:password-123@mongodb-primary:27017/my_database?authSource=my_database`

Comment: where is the mongoldb-primary come from ? and dont we put `?replicaSet=devrs` as well ??

Comment: what is `authSource` for ??

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in copying the docker-compose. I edited the answer. If you use bitnami image, you can connect via the above uri. Here is the [doc](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb)

Comment: authSource is set because of this variable: `- MONGODB_DATABASE=my_database` you can change it to whatever you want

Comment: does that docker compose failed for the syntax ? not using `version: "3.7"
services: :)`

Comment: Yeah! I just put the services there ;)

Comment: how about if I run with `mongo host` ? I can't run it

Comment: Comments are **not** for extended discussion. Please consider [createing a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new), [updating the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62389046/edit), or [asking a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @AnaLava failed to connect shell `mongo -u admin-123 -p 'password-123' --host 'mongodb-primary:27017' `

Comment: You should be in the same docker network if you want to connect with mongodb-primary. If you are not in the same network, try using `localhost` or your server ip address instead of mongodb-primary

Comment: so how I can connect it then ? I can't make it run :( sorry @AnaLava

Comment: Where are you running it? localhost?

Comment: I just run in my go `mongodb://admin123:password-123@localhost:27017` got `context deadline exceeded` @AnaLava

Comment: If you are using the above docker compose, you should use `mongodb://admin-123:password-123@localhost:27017/my_database?authSource=my_database`

Comment: should I always put `my_database?authSource=my_database`  ? always can't connect to that database if I dont use it

Comment: No you shouldn’t always use that, if you define it in your variable you should use that. Otherwise simply remove it

Comment: @AnaLava aren't we just connecting to the primary node in "direct connection" mode here? Is there any way to actually connect to it as a replica set? Example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#connect-to-a-mongodb-replica-set