# how to run services in docker compose outside from docker network

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have app that run in docker, it is mongodb and I build it from my docker compose , but I only be able to run it inside the docker , can't run from in my local host 
this is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongodb01:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    hostname: mongodb01.dev.com
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb01.dev.com
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB=yes
    volumes:
      - "mongodb01_data:/bitnami/mongodb"
    networks:
      mongodb:
        aliases:
          - mongodb01.dev.com

  mongodb02:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    hostname: mongodb02.dev.com
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb01
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb02.dev.com
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb01.dev.com
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB=yes
      - MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER=27018
    volumes:
      - "mongodb02_data:/bitnami/mongodb"
    networks:
      mongodb:
        aliases:
          - mongodb02.dev.com

  mongodb03:
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:4.2"
    hostname: mongodb03.dev.com
    ports:
      - 27019:27019
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb02
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb03.dev.com
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=rs0
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb01.dev.com
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_ENABLE_DIRECTORY_PER_DB=yes
      - MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER-27019
    volumes:
      - "mongodb03_data:/bitnami/mongodb"
    networks:
      mongodb:
        aliases:
          - mongodb03.dev.com

volumes:
  mongodb01_data:
  mongodb02_data:
  mongodb03_data:

networks:
  mongodb:
```

I am trying to build mongodb replicaset, but I do love to run it from my localhost mongo , how can it make possible ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To ba able to run it from local host, you need to expose the ports.
Add `ports:
      - 27017:27017`
to your service. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389046/how-to-run-mongodb-replica-set-in-docker-compose/62389152?noredirect=1#comment110367930_62389152)

Comment: just updated my docker-compose.yml and add ports , and run `mongo --username root --password 'password123' --host 'mongodb03.dev.com' ` nothing happen

Comment: ok I can run by this ` mongo --username root --password 'password123' --host 'localhost' ` , so I dont need to use `/?replicaset=rs0` anymore for URI ? because I want create database in my mongo-driver golang

Comment: You don't need to add `?replicaset=rs0` as you are using the bitnami images

Comment: so my uri to connect into mongodb compass should be `mongodb://root:password123@mongodb03.dev.com:27017` ? or `mongodb://root:password123@localhost:27017` ?? @AnaLava

Comment: Mongo compass is outside the docker network so you should use `localhost`

Comment: so like this ? `mongodb://root:password123@localhost:27017` and then I can do transaction in my go, I saw you are a Go dev as well, I do this because I can't do transaction in mongo go so I must have replicaset

Comment: Yeah! To do transactions you need to have a replica set :)